# How to get descrete fourier tarnsfom

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, fourier

Could anyone explain me please how to produce descrete fourier transform of such signal?[image] There are no anymore information besides the picture in this task.

Comment: These are values. The d**i**screte Fourier Transform is a well-documented algorithm (Wikipedia, or literally thousands of results from your favourite search engine, every single textbook of the last 40 years on systems and signals…) that operates on vectors of values. So, what is your question, specifically?

Comment: My question is how to get fourier transform of that sequence, because I didnt understand how to do it. Thought that someone can explain it here a bit simply.

Comment: So, first off: sorry, we're not a "copy out an obvious source of information for me" service. So, we have to expect you to do your research and describe your problem with what you've read. So, really, have you tried understanding the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) article? What's been the problem with that? The question "explain everything about the DFT for me" is simply too broad, and underresearched, and will be closed here.

Comment: Okej, thanx for your explanation. I expected that someone explains in more details. Thought that here I can place a question on things I didnt understood. Thank you, you were the best explainer

Comment: You're still very welcome to read the source I linked to, and explain, in your question, what was unclear to you. It's about as easy as anyone of us would have written, so if you think we can knowledge magically appear in your  head with lesser lecture or work on your side, I'm afraid I'll have to disappoint you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- Look at the ratio between two adjacent samples
- Express the picture as a closed form time domain formula
- Calculate the DFT using it's mathematical definition or just look it up in a table

It's not entirely clear whether the sequence is supposed to continue or is supposed to end at the right edge of the picture. You need to ask whoever posed this problem.